# Why the trace norm of a tensor is a good approximation to its rank?

Tags: convex-optimization, tensors, nonlinear-optimization, tensor-rank

In many literature, they use the trace norm of a tensor to approximate its rank,
which is defined as follows:
$$\|\mathcal{X}\|_{\ast}:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\|X_{(i)}\|_{\ast}$$
where ${\alpha_i}'s$ are constants satisfying $\alpha_i\geq0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$, $X_{(i)}$ is the mode-$i$ unfolding of $\mathcal{X}$,  and $\|X_{(i)}\|_{\ast}$ is the trace norm of the 2D matrix $X_{(i)}$ which is defined as follows:
$$\|X_{(i)}\|_{\ast}=\sum_i\sigma_i(X_{(i)})$$
where $\sigma_i(X_{(i)})$ denotes the $i$th largest sigular value of $X_{(i)}$.

Comment: How is $X_{(i)}$ itself defined?

Comment: I've explained it in the text just now.

Comment: I am not familiar with this notion of unfolding, could you give a link or something?

Comment: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/07070111X

Comment: http://peterwonka.net/Publications/pdfs/2012.PAMI.JiLiu.Tensor%20Completion.pdf